# How to resolve "NVIDIA OpenCL platform not found - defaulting to first platform" Error

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, nvidia

I am getting the following error when running an opencl program using GPGPU-Sim.

Can any one please help me resolve this?

```
/home/gpgpu-sim/cuda/sdk/4.2/OpenCL/bin/linux/release/bitCoin
Starting...
WARNING: NVIDIA OpenCL platform not found - defaulting to first platform!

Error: Failed to create OpenCL context! FAILED

[bitCoin] test results... FAILED

exiting in 3 seconds: 3...2...1...done!

GPGPU-Sim finished running
"/home/gpgpu-sim/cuda/sdk/4.2/OpenCL/bin/linux/release/bitCoin" Used
rundir=/home/gpgpu-sim/GTX480_rundir
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I added a couple tags on your post to try to help those with more knowledge about this find your question.  I'm guessing they're going to want to see some code as well, so it would be great if you can add that.

Answer (score 0):

Open Computer Language is necessary for certain bitcoin miner. You need a driver for your Nvidia Graphics Card that supports OpenCL. That can mean downgrading your aktual driver.

For GTX 480 try the driver version 337.88